# Constraints are affected when changing size class

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I am using auto-layout & size class concept for my project.I have requirement to displaying different layouts for different screen orientation.So I have used concept of size class.

When my size class is Any X Any I applied constraints for all fields and when I change story board size class for Regular X Regular this constrains effecting there how can I stop them

Answer (score 0):

After selecting different classes you can go to attribute inspector, there you can see size classes on some attributes. Just change the size classes over there and updated the properties for that particular classes.

Answer (score 0):

For each size class combination you can define a whole new set of constraints by deleting the existing constraints and adding new ones if you wanted to.

When you change the selected size class from the selector at the bottom of a storyboard, your changes to constraints will only affect those for this size class combination.

So, as an example, if you change your storyboard's size class to `Regular X Regular`, and then delete a constraint, it would not be removed, as it is needed for the `ANY x ANY` combination, but instead it would set it as 'not installed'. Similarly if you add new constraints at this point, they will be 'installed' only for `Regular X Regular`, not for `Any X Any`.

If you are new to Auto Layout and Size Classes, I would strongly suggest watching related WWDC videos, such as [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-216) on the concepts of size classes, as they run through demos which should give you a solid understanding of what is actually happening. It is a bit of a minefield if you try and just hack it together!